# How to properly use Knex / Bookshelf with MySQL on RDS

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-rds, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have a `Node.js` application using `MySQL` on an `AWS RDS` with `Bookshelf` & `Knex` libraries. The RDS Instance have a `max_connections` value `90`. 
I am using the following as the connection object.

```
knex: {
  client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host: 'xxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com',
      user: 'xxx',
      password: 'xxxxx',
      database: 'xxxx',
      charset: 'utf8'
  },
  debug: true,
  pool: {
    min: 2,
    max: 20
  },
  acquireConnectionTimeout: 10000
},
```

```
const config = require('./environment');
const knex = require('knex')(config.knex);
module.exports = require('bookshelf')(knex).plugin('registry');
```

```
'use strict';

const bookshelf = require('../config/bookshelf');
const config = require('../config/environment');
module.exports = bookshelf.model(`TableA`, {
    tableName: 'TableA'
}, {});
```

I have many requests coming along to the application and sometimes crashes with the following errors.

> Unhandled rejection TimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a
>   connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a
>   .transacting(trx) call?

and

> Error: ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections

Also I see a number of connections (40 to 50 on an average) in the server `PROCESSLIST` with `Command` as `sleep`.

I suspect these error happen when all the `90` connections on the server used fully / knex cannot acquire a new connection from he pool when it tries to. What could be a permanent solution for this, and best practices for handling these kind of applications.

Comment: It may be worth providing excerpts from your code around creating and using the database connection.

Comment: Updated @RichChurcher if this is what you meant. Thanks

Comment: And an example of one of the requests/queries that is timing out?

Comment: Looks like new `knex` instance is created each time you're requiring `../config/bookshelf`

Comment: You can (and should) verify that RDS max connection limit is kicking in. Just use the standard RDS monitoring and focus on `DB Connections` metric. Also, are you running your app on AWS Lambda? That could easily get you dozens of lambda invocations running concurrently, each opening connections to RDS.

Comment: If you can rule out RDS limits (in which case, you need to consider up-scaling your db.t2.medium or use Aurora Serverless), you should investigate a known configuration issue that might be causing your problem: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1382

Answer (score 2):

I dont think it is the RDS `max_connections` that is causing the issue, assuming you only have one instance of the above application code running at any time.

Your application uses a DB connection pool, which can hold up to 20 connections. If all those connections are in use, then the application waits for up to `acquireConnectionTimeout` ms in your case that is `10000` before connection timeout.

So I suspect that your application either has a lot of db queries to be processed due to load or there are some slow queries hogging connections. This causes a backlog of queries waiting for connections that eventually times out. Investigate which might be the case and do update us.

Things you can try in the mean time.

- Increase `acquireConnectionTimeout`.
- Increase connection pool size.

If caused by slow queries then optimize them before trying the above.

Possible methods for logging slow queries:

- Enable slow query log on RDS.
- Knex [query](http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-query) event to log transaction duration assuming you are using transactions.

Answer (score 0):

When a client is finished with MySQL, have it disconnect.

Also, check the value of `wait_timeout`.  Lowering it will force disconnections rather than "Sleeping" until you come back.